# Calculate % change in each observation

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to calculate the % change in values for Argentina for the entire column and store it in a data frame:
[image]

% change is 2nd value- 1st value/ 1st value *100
say if a column has
`30`
`40`
%change is `40-30/30 =33.33%`

Answer (score 1):

Pls read abot [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Supposing `df` is your `data.frame`. Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(change = (Argentina - lead(Argentina)) / Argentina * 100
```

---